# Unable to prevent automatic horizontal scrolling on TreeView in base class when selecting an item in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to prevent the automatic horizontal scrolling on a tree view item when you select it in Silverlight.  And I'm trying to do it in a base class.

So far I haven't been able to manage it.  I have tried the following code, but it executes and then the thing just scrolls anyway when I select it.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyControls
{
    public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
    {
        private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;

        protected override void OnSelectedItemChanged(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            base.OnSelectedItemChanged(e);
            _scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _scrollViewer = GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't actually want to disable scrolling entirely -- if an item flies off the edge of the tree view I want the user to be able to scroll to it.  What I am trying to do is to keep the tree where it is when I select a child node that may be longer than the width of the screen.

I've tried RequestBringIntoView on a WrapPanel, but that's WPF-only, it seems.  I've also tried doing this on UpdateLayout as well as SelectedItemChanged.  All to no avail.  I can't seem to find a general solution that I can have another class inherit from and use.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

-Ari

EDIT: The bounty states that I need to be able to do it in XAML.  That was a typo on my part.  I'll take code solutions as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What causes the `ScrollViewer` to scroll is because every time the selection of the `TreeView` is changed, a `ScrollIntoView` is called (inside the `TreeView`'s source code),

```
this.ItemsControlHelper.ScrollIntoView(container.HeaderElement ?? container);
```

and it basically tries to scroll either the header or the entire `TreeViewItem` to the very left. I first thought you could modify both `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem` styles by removing all the left `Margin` and make the header the same left margin as the expander button. However, this solution only works for first level items as in the second level, there's an indentation before the item so if you click on it it will scroll again.

So I guess there is no pure xaml solution. The easist way to solve this issue would be, given that you've already got the custom control, instead of calling (I think there's a timing issue and that's why this code is not working)

```
_scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
```

you do

```
var scrollableRegions = _scrollViewer.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<IScrollInfo>();
            foreach (var region in scrollableRegions)
            {
                region.SetHorizontalOffset(0);
            }
```

If you really prefer xaml solutions you may as well put this code into a behavior or an attached property, and just drop it in using Blend.

Having said all these, another solution I personally think is better and have used it in my own appliation is, disable the horizontal scrollbar entirely, and use `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` for all my `TextBlocks` inside `TreeViewItems` to indicate the user there's more text. Also provide a `GridSplitter` to allow the user to resize the `TreeView` content to see full text instead of scrolling back and forth horizontally. But this is just my opinion.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @AriRoth, glad to help. :) would you mind also allocating the bounty points to me? thanks...

Comment: Done.  I've never allocated a bounty before, so I didn't realize that I had to click a separate button for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

A late answer for those not satisfied with solutions above:

As explained on [this MSDN dev blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88cdadf2-0805-4609-899a-f95927ba55f4/stop-automatic-horizontal-scroll-when-selecting-a-treeviewitem?forum=wpf), the tree view is scrolled because TreeViewItem calls its BringIntoView method on selection.
The event may be canceled by overriding its handler and marking it as Handled, as follows:

XAML:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

the handler:

```
void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e) {
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

The approach has drawback yet: direct calls to `tvi.BringIntoView()` stop working either, but it may be bypassed by setting a boolean flag before calling `BringIntoView`, checking it in the handler and resetting it after the call.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case the best way to achieve this is to get the scroll viewer inside the tree view completely out of the way by creating a bare-bones tree view style like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewStyle1" TargetType="sdk:TreeView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:TreeView">
                    <Grid>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="5,5,19,19" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then simply apply the template to your scroll viewer and wrap it up with an external scroll viewer, this way:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TreeViewSampleData}}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FirstLevelTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle1}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Now the tree view has no way to communicate with the scroll viewer and therefore it won't be able to scroll when an item is selected.

Keep in mind that this eliminates any automatic scrolling and only manual scrolling is now possible. You can still add your own automatic scrolling by using behaviors or TargetedTriggerAction(s).

Make sure not to set any sizes on the tree view, so that it grows freely inside the scroll viewer.

I hope this helps.